# Is it possible to use VS2010 class diagram to create interface and classes graphically?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

VS2010 class diagram is very illustrative. I can add class or interface to it graphically. And the code is generated automatically. But how to make a class derive from an interface **graphically**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Inheritance from the Toolbox, click on the Class, and drag to the Interface to derive from.
[image]